# form submitting in ajax and symfony validations

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, symfony1, symfony-1.4

i got problem that when i submit form in jquery/ajax i get the data and check isvalid or not and save it. but wen the form is not valid it does not do symfony validations it automatically redirect to the page with out saving anything...the prob is it check the validation but it does not display validation error instead it simply redirected.

```
//my action code
public function executeAjaxtest(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
  {
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
      $this->form = new UserForm();
      $this->form->bind(
        $request->getParameter($this->form->getName()),
        $request->getFiles($this->form->getName())
      );
      if ($this->form->isValid())
      {
        $this->form->save();
        $this->redirect('registration/ajaxtest');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks having no issue.
you should check with save method. Jus overwrite save method and check.

Comment: hi franklin ..the problem got solved long back. thanks for your answer.

Comment: pls mention your answer whenever you got it.dnt leave as it is.